# Algorithm design: inserting bags into containers with a limited size

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have to create an algorithm which requires adds a *n* number of luggage bags, each with a varying weight, into *n* containers each of which can hold 50kg. Each bag is loaded into a container in order.

An example string of luggage bags' weight is as follows (each number representing the weight of a bag):

`16 24 25 3 20 18 7 17 4 15 13 22 2 12 10 5 8 1 11 21 19 6 23 9 14`

There are two rules for filling a container with luggage:

1. A container can carry no more than 50 (kg) of baggage
2. If the next (unloaded) bag will cause the container to be overweight, place it in the next container

---

My final goal is to print the list of bags weight of each container. The example output for the example string of luggage bags would be:

```
Container 1:  16  24
Container 2:  25  3  20 
Container 3:  18  7  17  4
Container 4:  15  13 22
Container 5:  2   12 10  5  8  1  11  
Container 6:  21  19 6 
Container 7:  23  9  14
```

My current code fails to create the containers, and I am now looking for a better way to do this.

```
public static void insertBagsContainer() {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> containerArray = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    int tempSum = 0;
    int x=0;

    for(int i=0; i<bags.size()-1; i++){
        tempSum = 0;
        ArrayList<Integer> innerBags = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while (tempSum<= containerWeight){
            tempSum+= bags.get(x);
            innerBags.add(bags.get(x));
            x++;
        }
        containerArray.add(innerBags);
    }
}
```

Comment: You may be interested to know what you're being tasked to do is implement a simple (naive, greedy) solution to the [Knapsack Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

Comment: fitting the minimum part (which weight is less than available weight left) each time, achieve the maximum fitting overall - this is the greedy way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classic example of using an iterator.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int maxWeight = 50;

    ArrayList<Integer> containerWeights = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Integer[] weights = new Integer[] { 16, 24, 25, 3, 20, 18, 7, 17, 4, 15, 13, 22, 2, 12, 10, 5, 8, 1, 11, 21, 19, 6, 23, 9, 14 };

    Iterator<Integer> itr = Arrays.asList(weights).iterator();
    int current = itr.next(); //Get the first weight
    int containerWeight = 0;

    while(itr.hasNext()) {
        if(containerWeight + current > maxWeight) {
            containerWeights.add(containerWeight);
            containerWeight = current;
        } else {
            containerWeight += current;
        }
        current = itr.next();
    }
    containerWeights.add(current);
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(containerWeights.toArray()));
}
```

Prints:
[40, 48, 46, 50, 49, 46, 14]

Comment: This only works if the last calculation is less than the max weight. An exercise to the reader...what happens if you make the last number in the array 45? How do you fix the above?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a `Container` class that has two fields: `List<Integer> container` and `int currentWeight`, then a `boolean add(Integer luggage)` that returns a `boolean` value accordingly if the luggage was inserted or not. Then, you can have a `List<Container> containers` that will grow accordingly based if the luggage could be inserted or not.

In code:

```
class Container {
    private static final int MAX_SIZE = 50;
    private List<Integer> container;
    private int currentWeight;
    //luggage should be of type Luggage as well, just using Integer for sample purposes
    public boolean add(Integer luggage) {
        //implement it accordingly...
    }
}

class Bags {
    List<Container> containerList;
    //again, it should be List<Luggage>, just for sample purposes
    public void process(List<Integer> luggage) {
        //implement accordingly...
    }
}
```

The implementation details are up to you.

Answer (score -1):

Just consider each `innerbags` list a container.

To print out container 1 you would print out the list of bags in `containerArray.get(0)`.

Sounds like homework, so see if that gets you started...